# Problems with ant tstamp pattern - always a leading 0

Tags: ant

Take a look at the following portion of my ant script:

```
<tstamp>
    <format property="SHORT_DAY" pattern="d MMM yyyy"/>
    <format property="SHORT_DAY_FORMATTED" pattern="d MMM yyyy"/>
</tstamp>

<echo message="${SHORT_DAY}"/>
<echo message="${SHORT_DAY_FORMATTED}"/>
```

Today is the 4th January 2013, so I expect the output to be:

```
 [echo] 4 Jan 2013
 [echo] 4 Jan, 2013
```

But it is not.  What I get is:

```
 [echo] 04 Jan 2013
 [echo] 4 Jan, 2013
```

Note the leading 0 in the first echo.  For some reason, ant always prints it with a leading zero.  The only difference between the 2 properties is that there is a comma in between the month and year.

Does anyone know what this is happening, and more importantly, how to stop the leading 0?

Ant version is 1.7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had SHORT_DAY defined earlier in the ant file (yes, it's a large file!)

```
<format property="SHORT_DAY" pattern="dd MMM yyyy"/>
```

And since ANT doesn't let you override properties, my second definition (the one I expected to be used) was being ignored.

Chalk it down to another case of human error :(